# Incorrect BitmapDrawable dimensions

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

I'm initializing a Drawable like this:

```
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
```

The dimensions of the bitmap are 50 x 77 (confirmed with the debugger, this values are set in the fields mWidth and mHeight).

But my drawable initializes size 33 x 51, why is this?

I examined the drawable variable just after this line, the values are:

mBitmapWidth = 33

mBitmapHeight = 51

And

```
drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
```

also returns 33 x 51.

But the drawable also has the bitmap field mBitmap, which has the correct size 50 x 77. So why is the drawable being initialized with 33 x 51?

Comment: isn't it somehow related to screen density ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dimensions of the `Bitmap` are in **pixels** whereas the dimensions of the `Drawable` are in **dp** (density dependent pixels).

In your case, the density of your display is probably something like 1.5:

> 50 / 33 = 77 / 51 = 1.5

Note that the drawable dimensions are updated when settings the density via `setTargetDensity` method.

Comment: Hm ok, but why the dimensions of a Drawable instantiated with `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mydrawable)` are in pixels? (I'm getting this problems exactly because of this mismatch). And also nothing about it in the documentation...

Comment: That's a good question... I noticed that the drawable dimensions are updated when settings the density via `setTargetDensity`, so I guess that `getResources().getDrawable` doesn't set the density

Comment: Ok. You both are right, here the dimensions are adjusted `private void computeBitmapSize() {
        mBitmapWidth = mBitmap.getScaledWidth(mTargetDensity);
        mBitmapHeight = mBitmap.getScaledHeight(mTargetDensity);
    }`, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[`BitmapDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#BitmapDrawable%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29) adjusts the dimension of your Bitmap to the density of your device.

Note that the constructor you are using is deprecated and that the documentation recommends using [`BitmapDrawable(Resources res, Bitmap bitmap)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#BitmapDrawable%28android.content.res.Resources,%20android.graphics.Bitmap%29)